# Set dynamic javascript value to html text input with sum

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please read the form and javascript carefully. My goal is grab text input value 'a' and 'b' then total integer value will be dynamically set to text input id called- 'x'. How can i set dynamic javascript value to html text input? Also it should be real time updating so user can see the total value of a+b on x. x is actually displaying the value and will be submitting this value if 'submit' button pressed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">

<input type="text" id="a" value="5">
<input type="text" id="b" value="2">
<input type="text" id="x" value="dynamic_value_from_javascript">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>



<script type='text/javascript'>

        $('#a').keyup(updatetxt);
        $('#a').keydown(updatetxt);

        var a = $('#a');
        var b = $('#b');
        var x = a+b;

        function updatetxt() {
            $('#x').val($(x).val());
        }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use html attribute onchange on text inputs a and b to call same javascript function updatetxt. In the function updatetxt, sum the value when both values of a and b are not blank.  Make your function like this. var a = $("#a"); var b = $("#b"); if a and b are not blank or undefined, var x = a + b; $("#x").val (x); else $("#x").val ('');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, I have fixed them below:

1. You need to get values of a and b during the keyup events.
2. You need subscribe to keyup events of both `a` and `b` inputs.
3. In order to add integer values, you can use `parseInt`
4. Call `updatetxt` for the first time without any events, so that it can set the total value based on default values in the inputs

```js
$('#a').keyup(updatetxt);
$('#b').keyup(updatetxt);

function updatetxt() {
  var a = $('#a').val();
  var b = $('#b').val();
  var x = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);

  $('#x').val(x);
}


updatetxt();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a" value="5">
<input type="text" id="b" value="2">
<input type="text" id="x" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle I have made recently,It will update real time. let me know if any query occurs

```
$(function() {
    $( "#a" ).keyup(function() {
    var a = $('#a').val();
   var b = $('#b').val();
  var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
  $('#c').val(c);
    });
  $( "#b" ).keyup(function() {
    var a = $('#a').val();
  var b = $('#b').val();
  var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
  $('#c').val(c);
    });
});

<input type="text" id="a" value="1"/><br>
<input type="text" id="b" value="2"/><br>
<input type="text" id="c" value=""/><br><br>
```

[My Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/z4dwc12p/1/)